# Is there a pseudo-class selector for javascript modified nodes?

Tags: javascript, css, pseudo-class

```js
function myfunc(){
    document.getElementById("bob").innerText += "azerty"; 
}
```

```css
#bob{
    color: green;
    transition: all 1s;
}
#bob:modified{ /* ":modified" pseudo-class doesn't exists; I'm searching for the good one */
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>I would like the green text below to turn red when it changes and then green again.</div>
<div id="bob">azerty</div>
<button onclick="myfunc();">click to modify</button>
```

I want to create a transition when I modify the text of my node via javascript. Is there a selector for nodes whose content is modified?

I tried ":first-child" by deleting then recreating the node, and ":defined", but it did not work.

I would like the transition to apply when the text is changed.

Comment: No. "Modified" is not a state.

Comment: of course, since you're using javascript to modify the element, why not add a class to it when you do so ... （⊙ｏ⊙）

Comment: @Jaromanda X If I do this, it will only work once, right?

Comment: @JeromeDemantke If you change back the text, you'd remove the class again. Or use a different class. That's what transitions between states are. If you want to fire off an animation when you run some code, use a CSS animation instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [Web Animations API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API) for this, instead of CSS transitions:

```js
const el = document.getElementById("bob");
const [modifiedAnimation] = el.getAnimations();
modifiedAnimation.pause(); // don't run immediately
function myfunc(){
    el.innerText += "azerty";
    modifiedAnimation.play();
}
```

```css
#bob {
    color: green;
    animation: modified 1s;
}
@keyframes modified {
    50% {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

```html
<div>I would like the green text below to turn red when it changes and then green again.</div>
<div id="bob">azerty</div>
<button onclick="myfunc();">click to modify</button>
```

Above is a mix of CSS animations with JS, you can also do it entirely in JavaScript by using the [`animate` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate).

Answer (score 1):

as you use js an idea can be to add an attribute or a class to your element

```
bob.dataset.modified = true;
bob.classList.add('modified');
```

and use css selector to pass new style

```js
function myfuncClass() {
  const bob = document.getElementById("bob");
  bob.innerText += "azerty";
  bob.classList.add('modified');

}

function myfunc() {
  const bob = document.getElementById("bob");
  bob.innerText += "azerty";
  bob.dataset.modified = true;

}
```

```css
#bob {
  color: green;
  transition: all 1s;
}

#bob[data-modified] {
  color: red;
}

#bob.modified {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>I would like the green text below to turn red when it changes and then green again.</div>
<div id="bob">azerty</div>
<button onclick="myfuncClass();">click to modify by adding class</button>
<button onclick="myfunc();">click to modify by add an attribute</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's almost what I'm waiting for, 
I would like the transition to apply not only the first time the button is clicked, but every time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to jeremy-denis's answer, I found out how to get the expected behaviour.

```js
function myfunc(){
    let bob = document.getElementById("bob")
    bob.innerText += "azerty"; 
    bob.classList.add('modified');
    setTimeout(function() { bob.classList.remove('modified'); }, 1000);
}
```

```css
#bob{
    color: green;
    transition: all 1s;
}
#bob.modified{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>I would like the green text below to turn red when it changes and then green again.</div>
<div id="bob">azerty</div>
<button onclick="myfunc();">click to modify</button>
```

Comment: you can make it better by listening for a transitionend event rather than using a timeout, e.g. `bob.addEventListener('transitionend', ()=>bob.classList.remove('modified'), {once: true});`